# Sahi Automation- Record/Playback not working correctly for no 'id' attribute elements

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, ui-automation, sahi

We've been using Sahi automation tool for web application automation testing. However we've hit a hurdle that inorder to play a recorded Sahi Script the UI elements should have 'id' attribute to uniquely capture the element.

Hence due to this dependency we need to define 'id' for all HTML elements which is cumbersome and not needed according to me.

Are there other ways(or tools) which would successfully record / playback automated scripts for even UI elements with no 'id' declared.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)
Thanks in advance . Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for an id attribute. There are multiple other ways to access this element like

```
_link(4, _in(_div("divId"))); // the 5th link in this div element
// or by classname
_div("classname")
```

look here for more ways: http://sahi.co.in/w/browser-accessor-apis
I am pretty sure you will find a way to get this element with Sahi.

Regards
Wormi

Comment: hey thanks for the reply... is this option available with free version of sahi ?

Comment: It's from the Sahi OS documentation, so yes it is available.